# Adding or updating Company entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

Here I am trying to post a company view-model and update and insert according. But I feel I am writing it in wrong way or maybe there's a better approach.

Here's my code

```
[Route("Master/Company/Post"), HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CompanyPostAsync(CompanyViewModel model)
    {
        model.CountryList = GetCountries();

        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        var _viewName = "Companies";
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(_viewName, model);

        try
        {
            var find = await con.Companies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == model.ID);
            var currentUser = CurrentUser();
            if (find != null)
            {
                find.Name = model.Name;
                find.Alies = model.Alies;
                find.Line1 = model.Line1;
                find.Line2 = model.Line2;
                find.City = model.City;
                find.State = model.State;
                find.CountryId = model.CountryId;
                find.ZipCode = model.ZipCode;
                find.POBoxNo = model.POBoxNo;
                find.Telephone = model.Telephone;
                find.Mobile = model.Mobile;
                find.Email = model.Email;
                find.Website = model.Website;
                find.IncorporatedNumber = model.IncorporatedNumber;
                find.IncorporatedDate = model.IncorporatedDate;
                find.IsTaxApplicable = model.IsTaxApplicable;
                find.IsLogoPrintInReport = model.IsLogoPrintInReport;
                find.LogoPath = model.LogoPath;
                find.IsActive = model.IsActive;
                find.SaveCount += 1;

            }
            else
            {
                var company = new Company
                {
                    Name = model.Name,
                    Alies = model.Alies,
                    Line1 = model.Line1,
                    Line2 = model.Line2,
                    City = model.City,
                    State = model.State,
                    CountryId = model.CountryId,
                    ZipCode = model.ZipCode,
                    POBoxNo = model.POBoxNo,
                    Telephone = model.Telephone,
                    Mobile = model.Mobile,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Website = model.Website,
                    IncorporatedNumber = model.IncorporatedNumber,
                    IncorporatedDate = model.IncorporatedDate,
                    IsTaxApplicable = model.IsTaxApplicable,
                    IsLogoPrintInReport = model.IsLogoPrintInReport,
                    LogoPath = model.LogoPath,
                    IsActive = model.IsActive,
                    SaveCount = 1
                };
                con.Companies.Add(company);
            }

            await con.SaveChangesAsync();
            CallSaved(true);
            return RedirectToAction("Companies", "Master", new { id = find?.ID });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CallSaved(false, ex.Message);
            return View(_viewName, model);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the redundancy by using the `EntityState`. You first try to get the `SaveCount`. Then based on this value you set the `State` either to `Added` or `Modified`. Something like this should work:

```
    var companySaveCount = await con.Companies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID)?.SaveCount ?? 0;

    var company = new Company
    {
        ...
        SaveCount = saveCount + 1
    };

    var companyExists = companySaveCount > 0;
    con.Entry(company).State = 
        companyExists
            ? EntityState.Modified;
            : EntityState.Added;    
    }   

    await con.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Alternatively the first query could be just:

```
var companySaveCount = await con.Companies.Where(x => x.ID == model.ID).Select(x => x.ID).SingleOrDefult();
```

so that you don't have to get the entire object.

Comment: `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.` Error I am getting

Comment: My bad I should pass ID also in company model which is key for the company entity

Comment: FYI: setting entity state `Modified` is sensitive to [data loss by concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30824229/861716).